# dotnet browser throwing Reload site prompt

Tags: wpf, dotnetbrowser

I am using dotnetbrowser 2.8 version

I have wpf page where I have 2 grids. one containing dotnetbrowser added to a grid and other contain a button. I am loading a webpage using dotnetbrowser and button present below to close the window/page.

I need to pass an integer value in url request every time to load webpage and I am using below code

```
public bool Index(int id)
        {
            LoadUrlParameters editId = new LoadUrlParameters(_actionIndex.Url + @"/" + id);
            bool b = LoadActionUrl(editId);
            return b;
        }

private bool LoadActionUrl(LoadUrlParameters urlParameters)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_browser != null)
                {
                    _browser.Navigation.LoadUrl(urlParameters);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The page loads first time without any issue but when invoked next time it throws below prompt .
"Changes you made may not be saved" with Reload and Cancel buttons

I tried using the handlers to suppress to popups and other ways but no luck.
Can you please provide me some help here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `BeforeUnloadHandler` to control the BeforeUnload dialog.  In this handler, you can programmatically select whether to "stay" or "leave" the page. See an example below:

```
browser.JsDialogs.BeforeUnloadHandler =
new Handler<BeforeUnloadParameters, BeforeUnloadResponse>(p =>
{
    // Dialog title.
    string title = p.Title;
    // Dialog message.
    string message = p.Message;
    // The localized text of the "Stay" action.
    string stayActionText = p.StayActionText;
    // The localized text of the "Leave" action.
    string leaveActionText = p.LeaveActionText;
    // Create and display the dialog if necessary.
    // ...
    // The "Stay" action has been selected.
    return BeforeUnloadResponse.Stay();
});
```

More information is available in the [documentation](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/gs/dialogs.html#beforeunload).